# Mostrar en textarea campos traidos de mysql

Tags: php, javascript

Hola quiero saber cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que seleccione una opción del select se vaya agregando a un textarea, cuando selecciono una opción me muestra esto en el textarea

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Login16\Login\vista\editar.php** on line **130**

```
           <form>
   <?php 
    $query_mostrar_tema = "SELECT * FROM materiales"; 
                           $mostrar_tema = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_mostrar_tema ) or die(mysqli_error()); 
                           $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostrar_tema); 
                           $totalRows_mostrar_tema = mysqli_num_rows($mostrar_tema); 
                            ?> 
                          <select id="tema" name="tema" onChange="actualizar()">> 
                          <?php do { ?> 
                          <option value="<?php echo $row_mostrar_tema['id']?>"><?php echo $row_mostrar_tema['nombre']?> 
                          </option> 
                          <?php 
                          } while ($row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostrar_tema));
                          $rows = mysqli_num_rows($tema); 
                          if($rows > 0) { 
                            mysqli_data_seek($tema, 0); 
                          $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tema); 
                            } 
                           ?> 
                               </select>
                               <script language="javascript">

                                var datos = [];

                               function actualizar() {

                              var select = document.querySelector('#tema').value;
                              var eltexto = document.querySelector('#eltexto');
                              datos.push(select);
                              eltexto.value = datos;
                              }
                             </Script>
                             <br>
                          <textarea id="eltexto" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
                            </form></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, el error del undefined index se debe seguramente a que el campo en la tabla materiales no sea exactamente "id" posiblemente sea "ID" o "Id", php es muy estricto en cuando a los arrays asociativos.

En cuanto a este fragmento de código:

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($tema); 
        if($rows > 0) { 
            mysqli_data_seek($tema, 0); 
            $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tema); 
        }
```

No aparece la definición de la variable $tema en el ejemplo que has aportado. No sé si influirá en algún error posterior.

Comment: Gracias , era la variable id que estaba  mal :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function actualizar() {

    var select = document.querySelector('#tema').value
    var eltexto = document.querySelector('#eltexto');
    datos.push(select);
    eltexto.value =  datos.join("\n");;

}
```

Comment: Hola! Tu respuesta está marcada como de baja calidad. Considera añadir una explicación de como esto soluciona el problema del autor. Para mas información te recomiendo revisar [answer]